# Background Image with fix size

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, slider

Hi please check the photo below, what im doing is i want to have a background image below the slider with the fix size

Css Code

```
.swiper-slider-bg {
  background: url('http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/bg-08-1.png');
 background-size: auto 100%;
}
```

**Current code**
[image]

**What I need to have**
[image]

Comment: Does not make sense what you are and where you are trying to get. Also, you need to show the context you are in (in other words the code you are using)

Answer (score 0):

Define it in pixels instead of percentage. Or, as a much flexible alternate, you may also use pseudo to achieve the same.

**:before** or **:after** selector shall be useful for you. I am hoping that you know how to use these selectors so not explaining that stuff.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is you need to want, refer below links for your use, It will be use your full page image slider.

```
https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/tryit.asp? filename=tryw3css_slideshow_self

https://codepen.io/jibbon/pen/BoisC
```